# Errror fetching data with promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise

I am new with promise and I can not to solve an issue with promise.
I have to return a new state in function loadPosts after fetching data from API:

```
[loadPosts]: (state, index) => {

   fetchPosts().then( data => {
      return {
         ...state,
         postState : {
            postList : data.data
         }
      }            
    })
}
```

And this is my **fetchPosts** function:

```
export const fetchPosts = () => {

   console.log("Fetch posts...");
   fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/post')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => {
      return data
    })
   .catch(error => console.error(error))

}
```

I get **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"**

In my understanding, first and second *then* of **fetchPosts** function, should return a promise with resolved value but instead I get undefined.

If I change fetch post in this way (adding return):

```
export const fetchPosts = () => {
   console.log("Fetch posts...");
   return fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/post')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => {
      return data
   })
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
 }
```

I get another error:  **reducer "app" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state.**

How can I use promise to reach my goal?

Thanks

Comment: You are not returning the promise from `fetchPosts`.

Comment: Thanks @Jaime, how I can return promise?

Comment: Not sure how that works in React. Try googling your second error.

Comment: `return fetch(........`  Promises are like a chain, if you don't return your promise, you will break the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, lets fix your `fetchPosts` function

```
export const fetchPosts = () => {
   console.log("Fetch posts...");
   return fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/post')
   .then(response => response.json())
   // the following code is not needed at all
   //.then(data => {
   //   return data
   // })
   // I prefere not to do the error handling here,
   // instead let the caller handle the error
   .catch(error => console.error(error))

}
```

Now that the fetch posts function actually returns something, I can only tell you that there is no way from inside the function in your first code snippet to return a new state with the posts that the `fetchPosts` promise resolves to. 
It looks a lot like a reducer though, so I recommend you take a look at [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) that allows you to enhance redux with a middleware for async behavior and you can then dispatch functions to the store that returns promises.

Comment: This answer helped me to solve problem.
I have inverted control flow, because I didn't find a way to return data after async call. So I dispatch via redux-thunk the call to API in order to fetch data and after using "then" I dispatch another call to update the state.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You need to return the `fetch()` so that you can chain a `.then()`.

2.) You need to have a default case in your reducer which returns the `state`.